# No .tmp file for streaming videos in Temp folder of Windows Xp

Tags: windows-xp, video, temporary-files

I am on Windows XP professional sp2.
When i open any youtube video on any browser , `.tmp` files are not created in temp folder.
i was able to download videos with this trick previously but i don't know what thing are preventing the `.tmp` file to be created.

may be i have changed some setting Accidentally. but i don't know what settings ?

So, how can i make it work again ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you're not looking at the right TMP folder...

Use this NirSoft's *VideoCacheView* and make your life easier:

[VideoCacheView Web page](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html)